# Gitlab-runner status showing not-compatible" reason="GitLab Runner >= 9.0

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Please let me know what gitlab-runner version i should use to make it compatible with the gitlab

Gitlab version

```
8.4.2
```

gitlab-runner

```
Version:      9.3.0
Git revision: 3df822b
Git branch:   9-3-stable
GO version:   go1.7.5
Built:        Thu, 22 Jun 2017 10:57:22 +0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Error:

```
Jul 27 20:13:02 ip-**-**-**-** gitlab-runner[20539]: time="2017-07-27T20:13:02Z" level=error msg="Checking GitLab compatibility... not-compatible" reason="GitLab Runner >= 9.0 can be used ONLY with GitLab CE/EE >= 9.0" result=404 runner="#%%_67" statusText="404 Not Found"
                                                     <nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the release note of [**GitLab** 9](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/03/22/gitlab-9-0-released/#gitlab-runner-deprecation) runners above version 9 use the [new v4 API](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/03/22/gitlab-9-0-released/#api-v4-ce-ee) and requires at least **Gitlab 9.0**.

So any runner version below 9 should do it.

**Tip:** *Keep the version of your **GitLab** instance always above your runners to avoid any problem.*

**To downgrade your runner:**

1. Uninstall it;
2. Download the desired package from this [repo](https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner);
3. Install the package.